# ASP.Net MVC routes work locally but not remotely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I know this issue has been addressed before but I have not found an answer to my situation. I have created a MVC website. When I run it locally everything works but upload it to our web sever the routes don't work and I get a 404 error.

Here is my local link 
http://localhost:49641/

Here is the web address 
www.hovdenoil.com

Let me know if you need any of my code.

Comment: Obviously, the local link isn't going to work for us.  Could you give an example of a route definition that works locally and doesn't work on your live site?  Can you give any additional information on your local environment and production environment?

Comment: Are you using separate controllers for each of the routes or is a common controller for all? Can you put a snippet from your route definitions in your global.asax file and the order in which they appear? Since it's providing a 404 remotely, that suggests that the route does not exist or is being caught by a competing route. If it works locally and doesn't work remotely, then you've likely failed to move a necessary file.

Comment: MVC might not be enabled, you may want to check with your hosting provider or admistrator of production environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like from the headers your site is sending you are running IIS6.  There are additional steps required to make routing work on IIS6.  You can read about them here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx

Alternatively, if you have the option, I would highly recommend upgrading to IIS7+, which works much better with MVC's routing.