# Why does URL Routing break when I use parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have developed an ASP MVC 5 website with the following route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{language}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Member",
            action = "Index",
            language = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
}
```

I only have that one controller, Member, and everything works running on IISExpress on my local dev machine. But when I try to deploy and access the site on my development server, I get 404 error. The URL I'm passing to it is identical to the one I'm using on the development machine, yet it seems like the routing is not working as expected. Here's a sample URL:

> http://myserver:8080/Member/GetCertificate/en-US?mn=MjMzOTA3MDc4MDA=&gn=NjcwNzkz

This is the only route registered on my application, and I've tried to register the wildcard script on IIS, as well as editing my web config with the following entries:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

The development server is running IIS 7.5. I have tried to access the page remotely from my development machine as well as locally from the web server, with no luck. Here's what the action method looks like for reference:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult GetCertificate(string language, string mn, string gn)
    {
        var member = new Member()
        {
            MemberNumber = Encoding.Default.GetString(
                Convert.FromBase64String(mn)),
            GroupNumber = Encoding.Default.GetString(
                Convert.FromBase64String(gn)),
            Language = language
        };

        var certificate = this.certificateRepository
            .GetCertificateDocument(member);

        return this.File(certificate, "application/pdf");
    }
```

I have continued debugging it, and I found that the problem seems to be that it's recognizing the action as the controller, so if I use the following URL, it works:

> http://myserver:8080/Member/Member/GetCertificate/en-US?mn=MjMzODU1NjE5MDE=&gn=NzkxMjgz

But I end up repeating the controller name, which makes for a not so readable URL. Any way around this, though? Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Is there a public URL to the dev site? What version of IIS are you running? This is just a shot in the dark http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010911/asp-net-mvc-routes-work-locally-but-not-remotely

Comment: What does your action look like? Looks like there's an extra equal sign in that querystring right before the ampersand.

Comment: I've added the code for the action and I believe the web server is running IIS 7.5. There is no hostname registered for the site, but I access it from within the network using the server name or IP Address. The equal sign is part of the parameter, and causes no issues when I make the requests to my development machine.

Comment: The `=` is a reserved character per RFC3986.  You should URL-encode it.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that the action returns a FileResult? If I change all of the parameters to query string, it gives me an error about not being able to find the Index or View. But the error seems to be reading the action as the controller, looking for /GetCertificate/Index, which it, of course, doesn't find...

Comment: Alright, I seem to have found a clue. If I repeat the controller, which also happens to be the name of the site, the routing works. But this controller is the default one, shouldn't it resolve regardless?

Comment: It sounds like the router is only getting passed the route info after the first `\Member`, which is weird.  Should be getting everything past `8080`.  If you go to http://myserver:8080 do you get to the correct default page?

Comment: No... But myserver:8080 is the site, myserver:8080/Member is the application. I think the problem was there is that my application (IIS) and controller share the same name. But I expected it to work, since it should still be the default controller, right? I guess not, though.

Comment: Ahhh, yup.  Get rid of that `/Member` in the application's URL and that'll do it.  The app itself is under `/Member/`, which means that you have to go to myserver:8080/Member to get to it.  If you had, say, `/MyApplication`, you'd have to go to myserver:8080/MyApplication/Member/GetCertificate/en-US?mn=MjMzODU1NjE5MDE=&gn=NzkxMjgz to get to the page you're trying to reach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my application within IIS had a name conflict with my controller. The structure in my IIS was as follows:

- MemberSite

  - Member
  - MemberService

And the controller in my MVC application was also called MemberController. This caused confusion, because I thought I was referencing the controller, when I was actually referencing the application itself. So for readability, I renamed the application in IIS to MemberApp, and the final URL looks like this:

> http://myserver:8080/MemberApp/Member/GetCertificate/en-US?mn=MjMzODU1NjE5MDE=&gn=NzkxMjgz